# django filter with the properties of the last object

Tags: python, django, time-complexity, django-simple-history

I am trying to refactor this piece of code to improve time complexity by reducing the number of loops.

```
items = DataActionItem.objects.filter(status='resolved', site_id=settings.SITE_ID)
resolved = []
for item in items:
    init = [resolved.history_date for resolved in 
                item.history.filter(status='resolved',
                history_date__lte=datetime.datetime.today(),
                history_date__gt=datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(
                days=7)) if getattr(resolved.prev_record, 'status') != 'resolved']
                resolved.append(max(init).date())
rc = Counter()
rc.update(resolved)
```

So far, this is what I have.

```
DataActionItem.history.filter(site_id =40, status='resolved',
 history_date__lte=datetime.datetime.today(), 
history_date__gt=datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).values('id',
'history_date').distinct().annotate(day=TruncDate('history_date'),
).values('day').annotate(n=Count('id')).order_by('day')
```

While writing this query, I got stuck at the point when I was checking the previous object. See below.

> getattr(resolved.prev_record, 'status') != 'resolved'

I would like to compare each object in the query set to the last object and only return the ones that their previous history objects do not have a resolved status.

If someone can help me cut down the number of loops in the original query, that will be great.

Comment: Can you add the model definition ? I think, you can annotate with a FilteredRelation your first query in your first code for retrieve the previous history item for each line and get out the query from loop (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects)

Comment: `prev_record` is a property of the simple history model and its not part of the model definition 

Comment: Yes but i supposed in the property function you make a queryset for retrieving the previous record ? So I speak about this queryset and the item.history.filter(...) in another. Probably you will get three queries generated by django but not a N queryset like now